# Simplify $\ln(\frac{6x^9}{3x^5})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to simplify $\ln(\frac{6x^9}{3x^5})$. My textbook solution says  $\ln(2x^7)$ whereas I get $\ln(2x^4)$.

I arrived at this by dividing $6x$ by $3x$ to give $2x$. I'm a bit stumped on how to handle the exponents. I thought that in the case of division I am to subtract the denominator power from the numerator power, hence I get 4.

How can I arrive at $\ln(2x^7)$?

Comment: Of course you’re right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\ln{\frac{6x^9}{3x^5}}=\ln{\frac{2x^9}{x^5}}=\ln{2x^4}$

Your have most likely just found an error in your textbook.